# How to double tap on a Map to produce an action

Tags: swiftui

I would like to double tap on the Map and toggle showThis.

I tried using simultaneousGesture and also using
Map(position: $cameraPosition, interactionModes: .pan). I also tried adding the .onTapGesture(count: 2) to the ZStack.
But these attempts did not work.

The following MRE code works when I use count: 1, but does not work
when I use count: 2 to double tap on the Map. For ios17.

```
 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI
 import MapKit
 import CoreLocation


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .camera(
        MapCamera(centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.77, longitude: -74.0), distance: 100000.0, heading: 0, pitch: 0))
    
    @State var showThis = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Map(position: $cameraPosition)
            // this does not work with count: 2, works with count: 1
                .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                    showThis.toggle()
                    print("onTapGesture")
                }
            // this does not work with count: 2, works with count: 1
            //                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture(count: 2)
            //                    .onEnded { _ in
            //                        showThis.toggle()
            //                        print("simultaneousGesture")
            //                    })
            
            if showThis {
                Text("showThis").font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```